# stuck with the maxsum works fine with small values but does'nt work with big values

Tags: java, arrays

the problem is I want to find the min and max sum of the no.of elements-1 elements in the array so i coded according to it but the problem is min value is correct for both small and large integers but max value is correct for small values only and when large values are entered the max sum is printed in negative.

```
 public static void arraymin(int[] arr)
   {

  int min =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]<min)
            min=arr[i];
        }
        int maxsum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]!=min)
            maxsum+=arr[i];
        }
        int max =Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
        if(arr[i]>max)
        max=arr[i];
        }
        int minsum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
        if(arr[i]!=max)
        minsum+=arr[i];
        }
    System.out.println(minsum+" "+maxsum);


}
```

if i enter an array like this it will give incorrect answer
For example:396285104 ,573261094, 759641832 ,819230764, 364801279
correct answer is 
maxsum=2548418794 minsum=2093989309

Comment: The answer is contained in your question's code: that there *is* an `Integer.MAX_VALUE` tells you something.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, int data type is 32 bit signed integer. The max value is 2^31-1. It can be accessed as

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

If the addition of 2 valid integers, overflows this MAX_VALUE, then only last 32 bits are considered and result is considered negative.

If you are aware of the input range, you can opt using `long` instead of `int`. Java `long` supports 64 bit signed number.